# How to generate random Double numbers in Google Sheets within range?

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking to generate a list of 50 numbers between `-.15` to `+.15` in Google Sheets

Both `rand()`, `randarray()` seem to offer positive numbers only. I hacked my way around n via a conditional `=if(F5>=0.5,1,-1)`, but this seems grossly inelegant.

Is there a better, cleaner way to create a list of positive and negative numbers within a given range? Wish `=RANDBETWEEN(-0.15,0.15)` would work

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be

```
=RAND()*0.3-0.15
```

so that you will have numbers between -0.15 and +0.15. Or to avoid decimals after .01

```
=round(RAND()*0.3-0.15,2)
```

Comment: Exactly, Mike. And for anyone who may not already know, an entire array of 50 numbers can be generated with an adaptation of this formula: `=ArrayFormula(ROUND(RANDARRAY(50)*0.3-0.15,2))` or `=ArrayFormula(ROUND(RANDARRAY(1,50)*0.3-0.15,2))`, which will generate a column or row of 50 respectively. For more precision, change the `,2` in the `RAND` clause or eliminate the `RAND` wrap altogether.